# Get last element in javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like so:

```
var myArray = new Array('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5');
```

How can I get the last value of my array ('value5') ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can get the last value of array with slice function like so:

```
var myArray = new Array('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5');
var lastValue = myArray.slice(-1);
```

Comment: If you knew the answer, why did you even post the question?

Comment: For trying " Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style" functionality and see the result. I do not think the community would be so 'aggressive.

Comment: `slice(-1)` returns the value in an array, so that should be `var lastValue = myArray.slice(-1)[0];`

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last element of an array the following way

```
var myArray = new Array('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5');
var last_element = myArray[myArray.length - 1];
```